# push live updates to client through Django Channels & Websockets when database get updated

Tags: django, django-signals, django-channels

I am very new to django channels.I wan't to try out. using django channels, If I added one user through django admin portal then this will be update on live on page where i am displaying users list. Using django post-save is this possible Please help me on this. I have tried one week on this till not get any solution.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how you can structure your question so more people understand your problem, and hopefully help you.

Comment: Yes check [channels data binding](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/1.x/binding). Only works for channels 1.x